# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework (1)'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

Error is as follows:
`C:\Users\[username]\Google Drive\VS2010\Projects\[project name]\[project name]\Views\Show\EditOrder.cshtml: ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework (1)' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

Hey all,
Got a strange problem here. *seemingly* randomly my project completely **borked** itself. A little bit of background: It's a ASP.Net MVC3 (.Net Framework 4) project that I mostly authored in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. I say mostly because you'll note in the verbose  error above I've stored it on my Google Drive. I'm syncing this project back and forth to my new development laptop, with an install of Visual Studio 2010 Professional. This probably isn't a great idea, but I wanted a simple method of working on it here on my desktop (at the office), at home (on my dev laptop), and on the road (again, dev laptop.)

Any ideas on what might have happened, and how I can fix this?

Bit more of background, now that I'm remembering this ... I had issues publishing it to our local IIS 6 server. I realized I had to add the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` to the package for it to work. At some point, I had deleted them from the project and re-added them. It was *probably* around that time, or at least within a few hours, that this issue started happening.

I can has halp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloody strange ..

Looking in my /[Project Name]/bin folder I found 4 strange files:

```
EntityFramework (1).dll
EntityFramework (1).xml
[Project Name] (1).dll
[Project Name] (1).pdb
```

In any case, after deleting them guys and doing a Rebuild, all is well!

(Anyone have any ideas as to *how* or *why* this happened? Might be a Google Drive issue, now that I'm thinking about it ...

Answer (score 1):

Your MVC 3 project has a reference to one version of Entity Framework, but actually finds a different version when attempting to resolve the reference to Entity Framework on the computer where you get this error.

The simplest solution is probably to update to the current version of Entity Framework on your current computer, where you get the error.

If you open your project's .csproj file in a regular text editor (e.g. Notepad) you should see a line similar to this one:

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.4.3.1\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

That will tell you the version your application is expecting to find.   If you see

```
<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
```

then the expected version or a later version can be used.

Another way to resolve this kind of loading issue is using the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx), which will show you binding attempts that fail and what the loader tried (make *sure* you run it as Administrator or it will silently just do nothing).

Comment: `<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0\lib\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

That's how mine looks. I should update this file somehow ?

Comment: I would update to the latest Entity Framework in the 4.x series (EF 5 is due out any day, I would not update from 4.x to 5 without planning dedicated testing time).  Then remove the reference to Entity Framework and add it again.

Comment: Well, I had to update Nuget to actually update EF, but it still didn't work. :( [link](http://pastebin.com/EEEYmpVm) for output of the command.

Comment: Did you also remove and re-add the reference to Entity Framework?  Do you still get the exact same error?  What does Fusion Log Viewer say about how .NET is attempting to resolve the Entity Framework reference?

Comment: I did, still didn't help. I've fixed the issue with my answer But can't mark it yet. Pardon typos and the like, on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Google Drive issue for me. If you remove all files ending with (1) in your Project/bin folder it should resolve the problem.